# Why is Stream protocol connnection socket closed and how to open it

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

Currently I have a lot of log messages

```
[warn] <0.7396.12> Stream protocol connection socket #Port<0.65372> closed
[warn] <0.7421.12> Stream protocol connection socket #Port<0.65377> closed
[warn] <0.7438.12> Stream protocol connection socket #Port<0.65380> closed
[warn] <0.7459.12> Stream protocol connection socket #Port<0.65383> closed
[warn] <0.7480.12> Stream protocol connection socket #Port<0.65386> closed
[warn] <0.7499.12> Stream protocol connection socket #Port<0.65390> closed
[warn] <0.7522.12> Stream protocol connection socket #Port<0.65394> closed
 [warn] <0.7547.12> Stream protocol connection socket #Port<0.65400> closed
[warn] <0.7564.12> Stream protocol connection socket #Port<0.65403> closed
[warn] <0.7585.12> Stream protocol connection socket #Port<0.65406> closed
 [warn] <0.7608.12> Stream protocol connection socket #Port<0.65410> closed
[warn] <0.7625.12> Stream protocol connection socket #Port<0.65413> closed
[warn] <0.7650.12> Stream protocol connection socket #Port<0.65418> closed
[warn] <0.7671.12> Stream protocol connection socket #Port<0.65421> closed
[warn] <0.7688.12> Stream protocol connection socket #Port<0.65424> closed
[warn] <0.7709.12> Stream protocol connection socket #Port<0.65427> closed
```

I don't know what is an issue with that

I'm running 3 nodes in cluster mode

I created stream queue i.e. x-queue-type:   stream

I have added exchange where in binding it's directed to this queue but I don't know whether it's even and issue

How to open Stream protocol connection socket?

To give more context. Logstash is also using it but gets constantly

```
[WARN ][logstash.inputs.rabbitmq ][main][some-queue] Error while setting up connection, will retry {:exception=>MarchHare::NotFound, :message=>"NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'some_exchange' in vhost '/'", :cause=>java.io.IOException}
    
[WARN ][logstash.inputs.rabbitmq ][main][some-queue] RabbitMQ connection was closed {:url=>"amqp://guest:XXXXXX@localhost:5672/", :automatic_recovery=>true, :cause=>com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: clean connection shutdown; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=200, reply-text=OK, class-id=0, method-id=0)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log `Error while setting up connection, will retry {:exception=>MarchHare::NotFound, :message=>"NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'some_exchange' in vhost '/'", :cause=>java.io.IOException}` was caused that I created exchange after running logstash. I should have create exchange before running logstash.

Answer (score 1):

Stream queues are divided into two sections:

1. [Core-Stream queues](https://www.rabbitmq.com/streams.html)
2. [Stream Plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/stream.html)

The first one is built-in with rabbitmq 3.9
The second one can be enabled using:

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_stream
```

if you want the UI plugin:

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_stream_management
```